# How to build http server in flutter mobile app as a background service?

Tags: flutter, http

Is it possible to build a http server in flutter mobile app but like Android service, a background process to work constantly?

I found a solution to add a http server to flutter app [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63426705/how-to-create-http-server-app-in-flutter) but it is not as a background process.